# IBOutlet is NIL when using Forward Declarations to call a class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, nszombie

I have been having huge issues with this, so I drew a diagram...

[alt text http://tomsfil.es/7bdead0a.png](http://tomsfil.es/7bdead0a.png)

I successfully get to the CLASS A - METHOD B but at that point, IBOutlet Z is Nil? :(
Any ideas?

*note*
Somebody told me it might be an Overrelease and to use NSZombieEnabled but that confused me

Comment: I don't get the meaning of your diagram. Care to explain with words the interactions?

Comment: There isn't an answerable question here;  no code and the image doesn't show up.  Need more information.

Comment: so what is the question here? you want ideas about? how to successfully get to A::B from Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all a matter of when you call the class.  Right after you create a view controller with initWithNibName, nothing is actually wired up yet - it's only after the view is created that IBOutlets are created and wired in.

One trick is that you can simply ask the view controller for .view, like so:

```
myViewController.view;
```

Then the view will be created and the IBOutlet will exist. A better method though, is to create properties on the view controller that you set, and then either in `viewDidLoad`, or in `viewWillAppear` you use those properties to set values for your outlets.